# How do scipy.stats.<distribution>.fit methods work?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, pearson

How do distribution fitness-tests, ex. `scipy.stats.norm.fit` work? Investigation of scipy source code led me to [`rv_continuous.fit`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/0650eac9e01d91f636ef266e8b94f0602bae3c17/scipy/stats/distributions.py#L1790) method, but it looks like beating the air. What algorithms are used, [Pearson's chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_for_fit_of_a_distribution) or some other ones?

**UPD** As I understood optimization algorithm inside `fit` finds maximum likelihood estimation. But for example for `scipy.stats.norm`, maximum likelihood is well-known - it is sample mean for normal mean and square root from sample variance - for sigma. Why it isn't calculated direclty?

Comment: *"Why it isn't calculated directly?"*  In recent versions of scipy, the MLE parameters computed by the `fit()` method are calculated directly for a few of the distributions, including `norm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All rv_continuous.fit seems to be doing is act as a wrapper method for various functions, beginning with fmin, in the [optimize class](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/optimize.py), using the [downhill simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method).